# Why was this question made community wiki?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, community-wiki

Per my understanding, conversion to community wiki does not occur automatically (anymore).

But this question seems to be converted to CW after [15th answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/28304/revisions) was posted to it: [Selecting interview attire for a technical job interview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/83/selecting-interview-attire-for-a-technical-job-interview)

How did that happen?

- Related: [Stop using community wiki as a reputation denial mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/165773)

  > <sup>Community wiki isn't a tool for reputation denial. We originally had all these automatic triggers mostly to leverage existing systems to handle abuse situations. While it can be said that it "worked", it also very largely didn't work, and a lot of pain was had by people who had legitimate contributions or labored tirelessly on their posts only to be basically slapped in the face.</sup>
  >
  > <sup>That ends today. I'm happy to announce that we have **removed all of the automatic triggers that convert a post to community wiki**. Edits by the original author, edits by other people, and even volume of answers, all of these no longer cause a post to be automatically converted to community wiki. There will instead be flags for moderator action cast in these situations, but they are mostly to let moderators be aware of what is going on with posts. That will help take care of the actual abuse scenarios, and as an added bonus, it means that moderators will not only know that such things happened but also be able to speak directly to abusive users and take additional measures as necessary. Community wiki shouldn't be even on one's mind when viewing these flags.</sup>
  >
  > <sup>The blog post [Putting the Community back in Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) discusses the intent behind the change, why it was assessed, and the impact we hope for the change. This was, after all, not just a mechanical change, but **a shift for the whole ideal of Community Wiki to remove its punitive usage**...</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [timeline for the question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/83/revisions) you will see that the question was made a community wiki in October 2013, prior to the change discussed in the linked meta discussion.

All answers to a CW question are automatically changed to CW themselves, which is why that specific answer shows that it was made CW today.

This is behavior as intended as far as I can tell.

Comment: thanks! seems to be at least 2 deleted answers there, I couldn't see that. Consider protecting the question as it seems to attract garbage and spam (with a title like that and ~20K views, why wouldn't it)